# How to print chunks containing errors without printing them in R Markdown?

Tags: html, r, error-handling, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit chunks that contain errors into an HTML file but without printing the errors — just the chunk.

While trying to solve this, I learned interesting information such as :

- [Hiding the result of a chunk that doesn't contain errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710427/how-to-show-code-but-hide-output-in-rmarkdown)
- [Prettying the error](https://selbydavid.com/2017/06/18/rmarkdown-alerts/)
- [Preventing chunk evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039673/prevent-chunk-evaluation-in-r-notebook-interactive)

I also found :

- [Basic chunk options and inputs](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results)

and

- [A controversy about setting error = TRUE or FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280043/how-to-skip-error-checking-at-rmarkdown-compiling)

While this was useful information for further analysis, I still don't get how to print the chunk without getting the error.

Lets' say I want the following code to be printed in the HTML file, **but not the error** :

Actual code looks like this (**keep in mind that I erased the initial part of the R code so you can see the code**) :

```
include=TRUE, echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=TRUE, results='hide', warn.conflicts=FALSE}

ggplot(df, aes(y = ABC, x = 123)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: If you're wanting to print just the code, why not try `eval = FALSE`?

Comment: Just tested it. It works just as expected. Thank you very much !